# Did António de Spínola request a Spanish intervention in Portugal?

Tags: spain, portugal, 1970s

The English Language Wikipedia [article on the Iberian Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iberian_Pact) claims that "*In March 1975, after the Carnation Revolution in Portugal, [António de Spínola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B3nio_de_Sp%C3%ADnola) attempted to invoke the pact to demand Spanish intervention. This was rejected by Franco.*" and this is referenced using a book I can't access:  Gillespie, Richard (2005). Democratic Spain: Reshaping External Relations in a Changing World. Routledge. p. 27. ISBN 9781134829408.

Although March 1975 is the date of [an intended coup](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golpe_de_11_de_Mar%C3%A7o_de_1975) leaded by Spínola, I can't find any other source mentioning a Spanish intervention. Additionally, such an intervention doesn't seem to be in line with the remaining of Spínola's actions and ideas, and even with a lot of imagination I can't see how anybody could have expected that a military intervention from a fascist dictatorship could further Spínola's goals (namely avoiding Portugal becoming a communist regime and turning it into something more or less like a Western European democracy). Furthermore, Francoist Spain had its own problems (avoiding any kind of Carnation Revolution in Spain among them) and trying to invade Portugal seems the fastest way to aggravate those problems.

Of course, after his coup failed, Spínola fled to Spain and at least needed to ask the Spanish government permission to transit through Spain and not to be returned to Portugal, but that's different from asking for a Spanish intervention, as Wikipedia claims.

Did António de Spínola request in March 1975 or at any other moment an Spanish intervention in Portugal?

Comment: Gillespie says: "when General Spinola requested Spanish assistance in March 1975, Franco turned him down on the grounds that the Iberian Pact (which he and Caetano had renewed in 1970) was dead."